# My front brakes contact the rim at different times instead of simultaneously. Is that normal or are they misaligned?

Tags: brakes, hybrid-bike, brake-levers, brake-pads

here's the video for reference

When I lightly apply the brakes only one part makes contact with the wheel which makes a squeaking noise.

How can I change this? I'm afraid one part of the brakes will wear much quicker than the other, also I don't know if it is due to this but my brakes don't feel as "tight" or responsive anymore.

Comment: You could move your pads a touch closer to the rim, the downside though is if your wheel is slightly out of true they may rub without any brakes applied

Comment: Firstly, is your rim true? No point in adjusting for the current contact point if it's going to be wrong in a 1/4 turn...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When I lightly apply the brakes only one part makes contact with the wheel

There are two adjustment screws (*Spring tension centering screw* on the picture below) which are meant to center pads of V-brakes. Screwing one in makes a corresponding pad to move farther from the rim, screwing it out does the opposite. It makes sense to loosen one screw a ¼ turn and simultaneously to tighten the opposite one by the same ¼ turn, control the result and repeat it until you are satisfied with the alignment.

[image: Anatomy of V brakes]

> my brakes don't feel as "tight" or responsive anymore.

Pads wear over time, which makes their surface to be farther away from the rim. This feels at the brake lever, it has to travel more until the pads hit the rim. This can be compensated by either screwing out the adjusting barrel at the lever (the picture below), or, if that option has been exhausted, by repositioning the cable at the brake cable anchor bolt (the picture above).

[image: lever]

However, if you see the need to re-tighten the cable at the bolt, if often means that the pads are already almost worn. At this point, replacing the brake pads may be a better solution. Of course, with new pads the adjusting barrel has to be returned back all the way into the lever to allow future wear adjustments.